# 400 Bad Request when accessing a Sprint Rest method with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am trying to access an update rest method with AngularJs, but it is giving me `400 bad request error`.

Here is my code.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/loggedInUser")
public class UserController { 

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public AppUser updateLoggedInUser(@RequestBody AppUser user){
        return userService.updateAppUser(user);
    }

}
```

Here is the code for accessing the service from AngularJs:

```
App.factory('LoggedInUserService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        console.log('service injected');
        return {
            getLoggedInUser: $resource('api/loggedInUser', {}, {
                query: {method: 'GET'}
            }),
            updateLoggedInUser: $resource('api/loggedInUser/:id', {}, {
                update: {method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'}}
            })
        };
    }]);
```

Here is the code for accessing the service in my `app.js` file.

```
.run(function($location, $rootScope, LoggedInUserService) {

            LoggedInUserService.getLoggedInUser.query(function(loggedInUser) {

                $rootScope.loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
                console.log($rootScope.loggedInUser.username);
                if (loggedInUser.role[0].authority === 'ADMIN_ROLE' && loggedInUser.pristineAccess) {
                    $rootScope.loggedInUser.isAdmin = true;
                    $rootScope.pristineAccess = false;
                    LoggedInUserService.updateLoggedInUser.update($rootScope.loggedInUser);
                    $location.path('/admin');
                } else {
                    $rootScope.loggedInUser.isAdmin = false;
                    $location.path('/dashboard');
                }
            });

        });
```

When I remove the `@RequestBody` annotation I don't get a 400 error but the parameter doesn't get populated.

What am I doing wrong here? I used the same kind of code in another place in the same application and it worked fine. The only difference here is that the rest method argument parameter is an entity object and not a pojo.

Comment: Please explain what means the `id` path variable in request, why you do not use it, and show AppUser class and the json object send by the request. It will be simpler than trying to guess it all ...

Answer (score 0):

add  **consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE** to your controller method and check your POST content with web developers tool or firebug or simmilar tool

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public AppUser updateLoggedInUser(@RequestBody AppUser user){
        return userService.updateAppUser(user);
    }
```

Comment: Tried adding it but getting the same error. when checked in firebug i see a valid json object being passed. I feel its something to do with converting the json object to the java object. But not sure how to debug it.

Comment: I think there is missing @PathVariable("id")

Comment: i was under the impression that if its a object we use RequestBody and if its a primitive type we use pathVariable. im not 100% sure though.

Comment: @path variable is part of the url in your case it is the id as you have @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}"